# PHP code to send email to users suddently started sending email twice

Tags: php, mysql, email

I have some PHP code that extracts information from a table in a MySQL database and then sends it to a list of people whose emails are extracted from another table in the data base. This has been working properly since mid 2017 but in the last two weeks it has been sending the email to each user twice. Also, instead of echoing the list of people to whom the emails were sent, it echos that no emails were sent. I can detect no change in the code. Here is the code:

```
<?php // Sends notice to all registered users who have opted-in to notificatoions
      // whenever listings have been added since the last email notification
    require_once('Includes/Mysql_connect.php');
    require_once ('Includes/config.inc.php');

    date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
    $timeZone = date_default_timezone_get();
    echo "<br> Time Zone: $timeZone";

    // read date of last email
    $emailDateFile = "emaildate.txt";
    $fh = fopen($emailDateFile,'r');
    $lastEmailDate = fread($fh,filesize($emailDateFile));
    fclose($fh);


    $loginURL = BASE_URL . "/login.php?referer=".urlencode('emailnotify')."&lastdate=".urlencode($lastEmailDate);

    // Retrieve all events that have been listed since the last email
    echo"<br>Begining search for events...<br>";
    $q = "SELECT event_title, event_type FROM Events WHERE event_added > STR_TO_DATE('$lastEmailDate', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')";
    $r=mysqli_query($dbc,$q) or trigger_error("Query: $q\n<br />MySQL Error: " . mysqli_error($dbc));
    $numrows=mysqli_num_rows($r);
    $eventList = "";
    echo "<br>$numrows events found since $lastEmailDate<br>";
    if($numrows>0){         // proceed with emailing if there are any new listings
        while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($r,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){   //build the list of all recent event listings
            $eventTitle = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars_decode(stripcslashes($row['event_title'])));
            $eventList .= "  " . chr(187) . " (" . $row['event_type'] . ") " . $eventTitle . "\r\n";
        }
        // select all registered users who have signed up for email notifications
        echo "Selecting users...<br>";
        $q1 = "SELECT user_first_name, user_email FROM Users WHERE user_active IS NULL and (user_pref & " . WEEKLY_EMAIL . ")=1";
        $r1=mysqli_query($dbc,$q1) or trigger_error("Query: $q\n<br />MySQL Error: " . mysqli_error($dbc));
        $numrows1=mysqli_num_rows($r1);
        echo "sending emails to $numrows1 registered users<br>";
        $emailCount =0;
        while ($row1=mysqli_fetch_array($r1,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){     // for each user, create the email
            $email = $row1['user_email'];
            $firstName = $row1['user_first_name'];
            $body = "Dear " . $firstName . ",\r\n";
            $body .= "The following events have been added to Bay Area PhotoScene since " . $lastEmailDate . "\r\n";
            $body .= $eventList;    
            $body .= "To get the details click the link below \r\n" . $loginURL . "\r\n";
            $body .= "\r\n\r\nTo unsubscribe to these emails, login to your account, click on 'My Account' and change your Preferences\r\n";
            $accepted = mail($email, 'New Listings on Bay Area PhotoScene', $body, 'From: admin@bayareaphotoscene.com');
            echo "email sent to: $email was accepted? $accepted<br>";
            $emailCount ++;
            sleep(5); // slow down so as not to overload server
        }
        mysqli_free_result($r1);
    }
    mysqli_free_result($r);
    mysqli_close($dbc);
    echo "Emails sent to $emailCount users<br>";
        //update date of last email to today
    $today = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    echo "Today is: $today";
    $fh = fopen($emailDateFile,'w');
    fwrite($fh,$today);
    fclose($fh);
?>
```

Comment: It sounds like you might have some redirection happening. Maybe use developer tools or fiddler to reproduce the issue and see if the browser is being redirected multiple times (e.g. http to https or / redirecting to /yourscript.php) and causing the script to execute multiple times.